# Minikube: Kubernetes Ingress not reachabled / loads forever

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create an ingress for the kubernetes dashboard, but it loads forever inside the browser: Mac

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

```
minikube addons enable ingress-dns
```

```
minikube addons enable dashboard
```

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

```
❯ kubectl get ns
NAME                   STATUS   AGE
default                Active   4m13s
ingress-nginx          Active   109s
kube-node-lease        Active   4m14s
kube-public            Active   4m14s
kube-system            Active   4m14s
kubernetes-dashboard   Active   51s
```

```
❯ kubectl get service -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.105.2.220     <none>        8000/TCP   82s
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.106.101.254   <none>        80/TCP     82s
```

```yaml
// dashboard-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact  
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 80
```

```
❯ kubectl apply -f dashboard-ingress.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/dashboard-ingress created
```

```
❯ kubectl get ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
dashboard-ingress   <none>   dashboard.com   192.168.49.2   80      67s
```

```
// etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.49.2    dashboard.com
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
~
```

When I now try to load dashboard.com or also 192.168.49.2 in the browser, it just loads forever and does nothing.
When i try to load http://127.0.0.1/ I get a nginx 404

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ingress addon is currently not fully supported on docker driver on MacOs (due the limitation on docker bridge on mac) you need to use `minikube tunnel` command. [Minikube docs - Known isses](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues), [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13795)

Enabling the ingress addon on Mac shows that the ingress will be available on 127.0.0.1. [Support Ingress on MacOS, driver docker](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/12089)

So you only need to add the following line to your /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1  dashboard.com
```

Create tunnel (it will ask your sudo password)

```
minikube tunnel
```

Then you can verify that the Ingress controller is directing traffic:

```
curl dashboard.com
```

(also I used this Ingress)

```bash
kubectl apply -f - << EOF
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: kubernetes-dashboard
              port:
                number: 80    
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also forgot that I couldn't just reach to 127.0.0.1 in my browser because ingress needs the host header from the request to match. Connecting via dashboard.com now works.